# Filling in cells with a specific number of matched criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to create a formula which looks for unique values from a reference list and fills in the number of cells based on the number of matches it found.

In my [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QdsgwLiQrGU7Q2ySI5e5t3WZTpxfn86XDqyA4adkR68/edit#gid=2127433474), there are three separate lists with specific courses that would satisfy the given requirements for each area (science, English, math).  As a list of completed courses is generated (left column), I would like the blue areas to have the formulas to show that credit has been earned (ideally, it would be nice to show the course as well, but the word "Credit" would be fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Hi, Bardo. I've keyed a solution into H12 of your spreadsheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Credit - "&filter(A3:A9,match(A3:A9,D3:D9,0)))
```

The `FILTER` and `MATCH` functions serve to identify the unique values in A3:A9 that appear in D3:D9 (which we change to E3:E9 and F3:F9 in cells I12 and J12, respectively).

Depending on how the list of completed courses is generated in A3:A9, you may want to consider using the `TRIM` function to remove accidental leading or trailing spaces.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Credit - "&filter(TRIM(A3:A9),match(TRIM(A3:A9),D3:D9,0)))
```

Lastly, the `&` allows us to append the string "Credit - " to the beginning of an individual value, and the `ARRAYFORMULA` iterates the process across the entire array returned.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.
I inserted a new table (not just a single column) to collect values.  Is it possible to have the array formula populate a table (as shown in the example) rather than just a single column?

Comment: Resizing arrays can be tricky business, so I encourage you to have a look at this [Google Product Forum] (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/uYCgs70_qHc) for some potential solutions. I've also keyed in a slapdash workaround in your sheet in H18:I18. In either case, may I recommend either accepting my answer to your original question or editing your original question to for posterity's sake?